# MySQL Time Zone Transition_type_id

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I've successfully imported my local tzinfo into mysql and I've pretty much got all the details hammered down on how this data is stored and used, except for one field. There is a numeric field called Transition_type_id (in the table time_zone_transition_type) that appears to contain some kind of probably-important numeric data, but there is no lookup table and its function is not immediately obvious.

Yes, I'm aware that I can just use mysql's built in functions to take advantage of this data, but I'd also like to understand what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 4):

This query will knit together the various time zone tables and show the list of transitions for the US eastern time zone.

```
SELECT n.name, n.time_zone_id, z.Use_leap_seconds,
       tt.offset, tt.Is_DST, tt.Abbreviation,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(t.Transition_time) AS p, 
       t.Transition_type_id
  FROM time_zone_name AS n
  JOIN time_zone AS z USING(time_zone_id)
  JOIN time_zone_transition AS t USING (time_zone_id)
  JOIN time_zone_transition_type AS tt USING(time_zone_id,transition_type_id)
 WHERE NAME='America/New_York'
```

The `transition_type_id` identifies the type of transition ("spring forward," "fall back" etc). It does that by linking to the `time_zone_transition_type` table.  There are a bunch of values there.

The one bizarre thing about this collection of data is the bunch of negative `time_zone_transition.transition_time` values, referring to timestamps before the UNIX epoch.

Comment: Since the data is derived from the standard IANA time zone data, the negative values are likely the LMT base values for each zone.  This is normal, and shouldn't get in the way.